# I keep getting an error in OrCAD using a certain op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, spice, orcad

I keep receiving this error in OrCAD. I am trying to use an LM741 operational amplifier for my schematic but am unsure why I can't open it.

Error:

> *Placing symbol instance for Model LM741 failed because in Demo mode Library path opamp does not exist*

Here is the circuit:

[image]

I need to use the LM741 op-amp but maybe there is another op-amp that will produce the same results?

Comment: Is this a sign that OrCAD has moved into the 21st century and no longer supports the ancient 741? Maybe just wishful thinking on my part ...

Comment: @brhans - funny that you said that I was just reading about how old the part is. My professor is making us use a LM741 and I just don't understand why.

Comment: @GenoC `My professor is making us use a LM741 and I just don't understand why.` That's because textbooks (the 50-year-old ones and even the newer ones) have been using the model-741 for opamps. That was so even when I was in university (early 2000s).

Comment: Just simulate using another op-amp and rename it 741.

Comment: It's great to learn with a 741 because you'll face all the classic opamp issues right away and learn what they are and how to avoid them, instead of being surprised later on. But it sounds like your problem here isn't the opamp, but you may not have the required license to use your Orcad.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - I found the solution. Do you think it would help future readers if I post the answer? Or should I just delete the question?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, I guess so. I didn't know there were that many issues with the 741.

Comment: Answering your own question is fine. The issues are actually there with most opamps; they just appear at MHz instead of kHz, or microvolt inputs instead of millivolt inputs, or 0.1V away from a supply instead of 2V from it.